# how to access axios response in blade - laravel view

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How to access axios result from vue component in blade file? I tried accessing {{value}} within 'app' div also. But the error still remains. I want to generate partial views based on the value of axios response.

**IssueComponent.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Enter Accession No</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    name="accession_no"
    placeholder="Accession No"
    class="form-control"
    v-on:keyup.enter="getData()"
    v-model="query"
  />
</div>
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-info" @click.prevent="getData()">Check</button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
data() {
return {
  query: "",
  value: []
 };
},
 methods: {
 getData: function() {
  var self = this;
  axios
    .get("/issue-getdata", { params: { q: self.query } })
    .then(function(response) {
      self.value = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function() {
    });
 }
}
};
</script>
```

**create.blade.php**

```
<form action="/issue" method="POST">

<div id="app">
    <issue-component></issue-component>
</div>
{{value}}  ///////// Undefined constant error
<button type="submit" class="button-btn btn-success">Submit</button>
@csrf
</form>
```

**Controller Method**

```
public function getData(Request $request){
    $input = $request->q;
    $acsNo = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $input);
    $acsNoIssued =  Issue::where('accession_no', '=', $acsNo)->where('is_returned', null)->orwhere('is_returned', 0)->first();
    return response()->json($acsNoIssued);        
}
```

**The Error**

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Use of undefined constant value - assumed 'value' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: D:\ProgrammingSSD\laragon\www\ulclibrary\resources\views\issues\create.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Blade is rendered server side. By the time your vue component makes the request, that {{ $value }} is already parsed and is now a static part of your view.

What you could do is save the state (the information) in VUE, and read it using another VUE component that will display the info (instead of blade).

Guide for states in vue
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html

```
<form action="/issue" method="POST">

<div id="app">
    <issue-component></issue-component>
</div>
<display-component-value></display-component-value>  // Vue component that reads the state you want
<button type="submit" class="button-btn btn-success">Submit</button>
@csrf
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

easily  you can do such using js scripts.

you can make

```
<span id='uniqueid'> </span>
```

wherever you want in your html code

then instead of doing this => {{ value }}

you can do the next =>

```
document.querySelect('#uniqueid').innerHTML = value;
```

but you can't use {{ value }} beacuse blade accesses only on variables passed by php server.

you may use alpine.js if you want. This will make it easier to do this task.